# How do I fix this problem with vertices?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm modeling a car. the middle of the hood (the centerline of the model) was originally a single edge but then subdivided. When I grab any vertex along that line, this happens. It pulls up a single vertex like so. I am using a mirror modifier. What am I doing wrong? Comment and ask for any additional information you need. Thanks.

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" You are using NGons (faces with more than 4 sides) never use those, use [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Will do. I'm new to modeling so... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured this out thanks to Duarte. Wow im a noob. Ngons were my problem for anyone referencing this problem.